# How to show a directory structure(explorer) in tcl tk?

Tags: tcl, directory, hierarchy, tk-toolkit

I am not able to add nodes recursively in a treectrl. i.e. I want to show all the directories and files as in an explorer.

Till now, this is what I have. I am adding dummy nodes in each folder currently.

```
package require treectrl
treectrl .t -showheader 0 -selectmode single -showroot 0 -yscrollcommand {.y set}
scrollbar .y -ori vert -command ".t yview"
pack .y  -side right -fill y
pack .t  -side right -fill both -expand 1
set columnID [.t column create -text "Column 0"]
.t configure -treecolumn $columnID
.t element create el1 text 
.t element create el2 rect -showfocus yes
.t style create s1
.t style elements s1 [list el1 el2]
.t style layout s1 el2 -union el1
.t configure -defaultstyle s1

proc add_node {parent text} {
    set itemID [.t item create -button yes ]
    .t item element configure $itemID 0 el1 -text $text
    .t item collapse $itemID
    .t item lastchild $parent $itemID
    return $itemID    
}

set images [glob -nocomplain -directory "D:/Explore" "*"]
for {set i 0} {$i<=[llength $images]} {incr i} {
    set root [lsearch $images [lindex $images $i]]
    add_node [add_node [add_node root [list directory [file tail [lindex $images $i]]]] dummy] dummy2
}
```

Comment: You might want to peruse the projects listed in https://wiki.tcl.tk/15091 for inspiration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to use option `-tipes` of `glob` command. This way you can separate directories and files. And second, you need recursion to process nested files and directories.

```
package require Tk
package require treectrl
treectrl .t -showheader 0 -selectmode single -showroot 0 -yscrollcommand {.y set}
scrollbar .y -ori vert -command ".t yview"
pack .y  -side right -fill y
pack .t  -side right -fill both -expand 1
set columnID [.t column create -text "Column 0"]
.t configure -treecolumn $columnID
.t element create el1 text
.t element create el2 rect -showfocus yes
.t style create s1
.t style elements s1 [list el1 el2]
.t style layout s1 el2 -union el1
.t configure -defaultstyle s1

proc add_node {parent text button} {
    set itemID [.t item create -button $button ]
    .t item element configure $itemID 0 el1 -text $text
    .t item collapse $itemID
    .t item lastchild $parent $itemID
    return $itemID
}

proc add_directory {path parent} {
  set directory_list [glob -nocomplain -types d -directory $path "*"]
  foreach directory $directory_list {
    set n [add_node $parent [file tail $directory] yes]
    add_directory $directory $n
  }
  set files_list [glob -nocomplain -types f -directory $path "*"]
  foreach file $files_list {
    set n [add_node $parent [file tail $file] no]
  }
}

add_directory "D:/Explore" root
```